# My regexp in Java is replacing too much text when the pattern matches multiple groups

Tags: java, regex

With a string like so:

```
3 SOME STRING (remove me) 6 SOME OTHER STRING (also remove me!) 8 THIRD STRING (and me)
```

with the goal to strip away anything in parentheses and having the string turned into:

```
3 SOME STRING 6 SOME OTHER STRING 8 THIRD STRING
```

My best effort so far has been:

```
private String removeAnythingInParentheses(String input) {
    return Pattern.compile("\\(.*\\)").matcher(input).replaceAll("").trim();
}
```

This however replaces too much of my string and leaves me with (I guess it matches the first parentheses to the very last in the string):

```
3 SOME STRING
```

I am sure there are some nifty features of Pattern and Matcher that I could use but I cannot figure them out...

Comment: I have looked at these two posts, but still cannot seem to figure it out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34180794/how-to-replace-multiple-matched-regex and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27415584/replace-multiple-capture-groups-using-regexp-with-java

Comment: Use something like: `"\\([^\\(\\)]*\\)"`

Comment: Add a `?` after the `*`.

Comment: Maurice Perry: Nice one worked like a charm! Had two redundant escapes within the  [ ] which could be removed!

Answer (score 1):

As suggested by comment. The correct answer was:

```
private String removeAnythingInParentheses(String input) {
    return Pattern.compile("\\([^()]*\\)").matcher(input).replaceAll("").trim();
}
```

Comment: But please, make a constant of your compiled pattern: no need to compile it each time the method is called.

Answer (score 1):

I guess a simple use of `String.replaceAll` with a modified regex would be easier on the eyes

```
 input.replaceAll("\\(.*?\\)", "");
```

full code

```
    String input = "3 SOME STRING (remove me) 6 SOME OTHER STRING (also remove me!) 8 THIRD STRING (and me)";
    input = input.replaceAll("\\(.*?\\)", "");

    System.out.println(input);
```

**output**

3 SOME STRING  6 SOME OTHER STRING  8 THIRD STRING

Comment: That's more like it :) Thanks.